# USB port mounting

Tags: usb-drive

How do I find out what USB a device is in and get it to mount.I have done it befor but not in a long time and can't remember how nor can I find the notes I took to do it

Comment: What exactly do you want to mount ? a usb drive ?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this with external HDDs using Ubuntu 14.04 and 12.04, I'm assuming that is what you're attempting. I start with Gparted to identify the device, usually its /dev/sdb1 or similar.

Then I find the device, there is a drop down in the top right (at the moment) to change between devices. Once you have located your USB device select it.

I like to use EXT4 format. To do so:

1 - select the HDD (usually sdb1 or similar) note the path for later use

2 - Right Click and choose Format

3 - Select EXT4 (or whatever format you like)

4 - Click on the Green Checkmark to apply the changes

5 - Label the device by Right Click and choose Label, I stick with EXT-HDD for my external HDD

6 - Click on the Green Checkmark again to apply the label

Here's where it gets a little confusing. 
7 - After you have saved the changes, disconnect the EXT-HDD

8 - Leave it disconnected and shutdown (NOT REBOOT) your PC

9 - plug the EXT-HDD back into the same USB port

10 - turn the PC back on

11 - get to the desktop and open up a terminal and become root

12 - Identify the Devices UUID with this command and the path you noted from step 1:

```
blkid /dev/sdb1
```

13 - Note the UUID for the device

14 - Create the mount point you want with this command:

```
mkdir /mnt/exthdd
```

(or similar depending on where you want it mounted and pointing to) Note that mount point for later use

15 - open and edit fstab via terminal to look give it mount point and permissions

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

add the line (use tab between values):

```
UUID=<enter your devices UUID>     /mnt/exthdd     ext4     auto     0     0
```

16 - save changes to fstab

17 - give permissions to the created mount point

```
chmod 777 /mnt/exthdd
```

Exit terminal and reboot.

At this point your PC should boot fine and have a new mount point. Any issues start over and double check everything. There have been devices I can get mounted on the first try, and for some reason others take a few tries, so don't loose heart. To ensure it mounted, there should be no errors during boot also go to that mount point in your files and see what the size of the volume is, it should be about the size of your USB device.

Good Luck and Enjoy!

Comment: You do not have to shut down after formatting nor mess with /etc/fstab; usb disks are automatically mounted when you plug them in.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to mount a drive you've plugged in?

You can use the graphical file browser and just click the entry for it, or you can use the command-line.

If you use the command line, find out the path to the device and then mount it with udisksctl.

To find the path, I suggest checking the output from dmesg after you've plugged it in.  For example, I just plugged in a thumb drive:

```
user@host:~$ dmesg | tail -n 10
[29642.218520] usb-storage 3-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[29642.219007] scsi host7: usb-storage 3-1.2:1.0
[29643.217841] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Glide     1.26 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[29643.218263] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[29643.219516] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 15633408 512-byte logical blocks: (8.00 GB/7.45 GiB)
[29643.220885] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[29643.220891] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[29643.221893] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[29643.234250]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3
[29643.237733] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

So in this case, I have three partitions on my drive: sdc1, sdc2, sdc3 (which will all be in /dev/sdc1, /dev/sdc2, /dev/sdc3).

If you can't unplug and replug the device for some reason, you could just list all of your drives by their labels and see if maybe it's one of those.  For example:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 13 11:27 d_extra -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 13 19:41 Kali\x20Live -> ../../sdc2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 13 11:27 l_extra -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 13 19:41 persistence -> ../../sdc3
```

Once you know which device you actually want to mount, you can use `udisksctl` with the `-b` option to tell it what device.

For example, if I wanted to mount the "Kali Live" partition, I could do it like this:

```
user@host:~$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdc2 
Mounted /dev/sdc2 at /media/user/Kali Live.
```

Or, I could specify the by-label path...

```
user@host:~$ udisksctl mount -b '/dev/disk/by-label/Kali\x20Live'
Mounted /dev/sdc2 at /media/user/Kali Live.
```

However you do it, be sure to unmount it when you finish:

```
user@host:~$ udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdc2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying. I stopped using my printer several months ago and when I tried to get it going again it wouldn't work I have figured it out it was a in my system settings some how something got unchecked.It was a more simple fix then I thought thanks again for the replies